# How do I move my 2nd image to be in front of my other image

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I tried to create a tkinter weather app i put in my 2nd image and i kept trying to put it where its in front of my other image on top.

When I tried moving it by putting in x and y it didnt move any where ima post my code.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that illustrates your problem. It's unclear how you've added the images to your app since there's more than one way to do that.

Comment: Perhaps you could use different frames?

Comment: how to ask a good question:
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)